# how to set value in Text widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-text

My problem: I can't display the value to Text widget when I select a row.

how can I display a value inside the *Text widget* from the selected row?

I tried using *textvariable* attribute in Text widget but its not working.

[image]

Comment: Please post an [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us help you!

Comment: What is the code that refers to the image?

Comment: Writing to a text widget is covered by existing documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`insert`](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#basics) method of the `Text` widget. Minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()


def add_text():
    # text.delete(1.0, tk.END)  # Uncomment if you need to replace text instead of adding
    text.insert(tk.END, f"Some text\n")


tk.Button(root, text="Add text", command=add_text).pack()

root.mainloop()
```